# Cannot connect to internet

Tags: networking, server, internet, ethernet

My computer was originally running windows 10 when the internet stopped working - it would connect to our network, but no internet access. I had a play around but decided that I was considering doing the switch on my PC to Ubuntu and assumed a windows update must of altered something and so I did a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

There is still no internet access

ifconfig

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:9e:17:b8:2d:48  
      inet6 addr: fe80::ae9e:17ff:feb8:2d48/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3700 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:262288 (262.2 KB)  TX bytes:23450 (23.4 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:df200000-df220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:889656 (889.6 KB)  TX bytes:889656 (889.6 KB)
```

lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [8086:15a1]
DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [1043:85c4]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

Note I added in 'auto eno1 iface eno1 inet dhcp' - without this there is no inet6 addr in the ifconfig output.

I've tested the connection and cables by running through my laptop with the same OS (what I am currently using) with no issue. I have tried re-installing the e1000e driver and WoL is disabled in BIOS. Any advice would be great.

**EDIT**
killall -9 dhclient; dhclient -v eno1

```
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: All rights reserved.
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: 
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: can't create /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases: Permission denied
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G liamg: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: Open a socket for LPF: Operation not permitted
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: 
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: 
Nov  4 10:37:32 liam-G dhclient[2495]: exiting.
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it would connect to our network_ when you were still running Windows? Did you try ping, ssh or whatever packet transfer between your machine and any other local computer/router?

Comment: I was still able to connect to my network drive

Comment: You mean network file server ? Try to ping its IP in that case.

Comment: Yeh that's, just a western digital my cloud

Comment: Can you run `killall -9 dhclient; dhclient -v eno1` and look at the last few lines in /var/log/syslog .If you are fine with pasting them to us -  it could help, as I suggest the DHCP servers is not responding if the NIC is probably configured by the kernel. Unless you're using only IPv6 in your network.

Comment: I made an edit with the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47924/discussion-between-rostislav-kandilarov-and-freight-train).